# Yad: text selection via button OR input field

Tags: linux, yad

i want to create a yad command which displays 1 button and 1 input field. I want that when the user clicks on the button a predefined text is returned to stdout. And when the user writes something into the input field and presses enter/clicks on another button, then the input field text is returned to stdout instead.

How would you do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want something like this:

[image: OPS dialogue]

where `Default` prints a default value to `stdout` and closes the dialogue.

Not sure if it is possible without wrapping it in a script. You can use exit status to detect which button was pressed and take actions accordingly. One can get it to print to `stdout` but AFAIK there is no way to close the dialogue after without killing the process. If you capture the input each press on the button would result in an additional field.

The best compromise could be to use the `--entry-text` option with default value, e.g:

```bsh
yad \
    --entry \
    --text "Enter value" \
    --entry-text="foo" \
    --button=gtk-ok
```

Giving you something like this:

[image: yad default input example]

Optionally adding `Cancel` button as, if you use the data, you would want to check for Escape key and Closed dialogue by `×` (I.e. abort scenario).

It would likely be the cleanest approach but who knows. In addition user can easily change default value without writing entire text.

---

Using exit code from `yad`:

```bsh
input=$(yad \
        --entry \
        --text "Enter text or press Default to use ‘foo’" \
        --button=Default:1 \
        --button=gtk-ok:0)

case $? in
1) input=foo ;;
252) echo 'Aborting'; exit 1;;
esac

printf 'INPUT: %s\n' "$input"
```

[image: Parse exit status]

One get exit status `252` when dialogue is closed by `×` or Escape key.

You would likely want to validate if `input` is empty when `OK` is pressed.

---

Another approach is using shell calls, but then there is no way AFAIK to close the dialogue after text has been echoed and killing the process would be only way out (Note quotes). Yad exports `YAD_PID` when running:

```bsh
--button="Default":'sh -c "echo foo; kill YAD_PID;"'

# or

--form \
--input="Default":btn 'sh -c "echo foo; kill YAD_PID;"'
```

In this case one can also use a function, (note use of bash if bash script), e.g:

```bsh
foo() {
    echo foo
    kill $YAD_PID
}

export -f foo

yad \
    --button="Default":'bash -c foo'
```

---

If you can use `HTML` that is another option of course, but require Yad to be compiled with webkit. Mine is not.

Comment: thanks for the super detailed answer. I think solution with the error codes is the best for my usecase. I had hoped for a true "easy" solution without a script, but this is fine too

Comment: @Loading Once one understand and get the error code (should have used exit code I guess) scheme under control it is good. It's what I use in most circumstances as I find it cleaner. Not that I have used Yad or the like that much. I try to focus on it being intuitive for end-user first and code complexity second. But keep a decent balance. One do not want to make the code difficult to read and prone to (too much) bugs :) Just focus on doing one thing at a time: get input, check exit code, check response, ... compartmentalize tasks at hand and do one by one step by step.